# how can i pass a image data to controiller and convert into bytes

Tags: javascript, jquery, controller, base64

i am doing some in javascript like follows in front end

```
if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('#brandImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
            },
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
```

now whatever is there in brandImage is now looks to me some binary data of the image which is like src="data:image/jpeg;base64..and than some random characters..

now i want to transfer that data to the controller and in the controller i want to convert that binary data in bytes.

is this possible

Comment: What controller, in what language?

Comment: spring java controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this data is binary data already, so you can pass everything you get to controller, but it is encoded with base64, so you need to decode it

for java use http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e12063/oracle/dss/util/BASE64Decoder.html

just don't forget to remove prefix `data:image/jpeg;base64` from this data

Comment: how to pass this data to the controller ..as String or if no i would like to know as which object or like byte[] will do...

Comment: pass it as string, it will be easier